# Mat-input to prevent user from copy and paste letters

Tags: angular, typescript

I have validation when a user is unable to type in letters and can only type in numbers. However, a user is able to copy and paste letters into the input. I need assistance in preventing this from happening. I'm using the function below `keyPressNumbersWithDecimal` prevents typing letters but this doesn't prevent a user from copying and pasting letters into it. I am not sure how to do this and looking for help with a possible solution to this.

html

```html
<div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
    <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Breakfast</mat-label>
        <input
            matInput
            type="text"
            class="example-right-align"
            placeholder="0.00"
            formControlName="bfastAmount"
            (keypress)="keyPressNumbersWithDecimal($event)"
        />
        <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
        <mat-error *ngIf="pricingSFSPForm.controls['bfastAmount'].errors?.pattern" 
           class="text-danger">Please provide a valid amount.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

ts

```
keyPressNumbersWithDecimal(event: {which: any; keyCode: any; preventDefault: () => void}) {
    var charCode = event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode !== 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste

Check docs. It's applicable for input HTML element:

```html
<div class="col-md-3 offset-md-1">
    <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Breakfast</mat-label>
        <input
            matInput
            type="text"
            class="example-right-align"
            placeholder="0.00"
            formControlName="bfastAmount"
            (keypress)="keyPressNumbersWithDecimal($event)"
            (onpaste)="yourlogichere()"
        />
        <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
        <mat-error *ngIf="pricingSFSPForm.controls['bfastAmount'].errors?.pattern" 
           class="text-danger">Please provide a valid amount.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

Then, you can simply call the method within component with any custom logic you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent all action when paste,try to use (paste)="" event and preventDefault and stopPropagation with this way

```
    <mat-form-field appearance="legacy" floatLabel="always">
        <mat-label>Breakfast</mat-label>
        <input
            matInput
            type="text"
            class="example-right-align"
            placeholder="0.00"
            formControlName="bfastAmount"
            (paste)="preventPaste($event)"  // add this event binding
            (keypress)="keyPressNumbersWithDecimal($event)"
        />
        <span matPrefix>$&nbsp;</span>
        <mat-error *ngIf="pricingSFSPForm.controls['bfastAmount'].errors?.pattern" 
           class="text-danger">Please provide a valid amount.</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

ts

```
preventPaste(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```